# Isolated flybacks in series to generate high-voltage

Tags: transformer, isolation

I'm considering placing isolated flyback converters secondaries in series such as the image below. I want to drive the transformers individually using synced clocks (such each transformer has its own IC driver and opto-feedback) such that across each transformer is 50 V, and they are in series up to 600 V (12 converters total). I want to locally float circuits across each 50 V step and draw around 50 mA. The load across each 50 V rail will be the same as the circuits are duplicates. All of the primary drives would be fed off the same DC rail. I think a better solution would be by having a transformer with a single primary and 12 secondaries but I don't have the knowledge/capability to design such a thing so I am looking at this design with off-the-shelf parts.

Would this solution be feasible? I am looking at using transformers with 100 V secondary voltage rating and 2 kV+ pri-sec rating to provide sufficient isolation.

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149946/discussion-on-question-by-curious-diode-isolated-flybacks-in-series-to-generate); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My general advice is to never connect anything but resistors in series.

If you do need 12 individual outputs, spanning from 0 to 600 V DC, there are some benefits of stacking the outputs of 12 converters in series:

- Cross regulation

Downsides would include:

- DC stress on the topmost transformers
- Dynamic behavior at startup and faults

Your other option would be to make just one converter with 12 outputs, at which point you have more control over the DC stress in the transformer. 600 V isn't that high, but your average enamel wire may only be rated for 300 V working voltage. With tape or insulated wire, you could have the last windings have ample voltage rating. Downside would be cross regulation with just one feedback. Without for example post regulation in the form of an LDO, you're down to how well the secondaries in your transformer are coupled to each other and how much load imbalance you have.

Assuming the transformer isn't a limitation, you need to consider fault cases. The foremost I can think of is either if one of the converters would stop operating by some fault or just an overload from whatever is connected downstream of it. If there are any loads from for example +600 V to ground (across all converters), depending on how much it behaves like an ideal current sink and how much inductance you have, will try to force the converter not supplying any current to go negative. The situation is identical to a series battery pack where one cell is depleted before the others. If the load across them keeps pulling current, the depleted cell will eventually go negative voltage. BMSes are used to prevent this very situation.

I would recommend you to put a Schottky diode across each output to prevent it from going too negative to damage anything (capacitors, feedback) and ideally, a power good signal from each converter, probably via optocoupler down to some central MCU or similar to shut down the other converters if this happens. A BMS of sorts.

The schematic below is very simplified. As it stands, it won't allow the converters to boot. You need to inhibit the power good function for some time until they are expected to be up and running. It's just to give you an idea on how to catch problems. D4 and D14 are Schottky diodes. It may be possible to hook into the existing feedback loops and determine if a converter has lost regulation, but it's the same startup behavior you need to catch as they all start from zero yet there is nothing wrong.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8sGi4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - this is clear. What value of R1/R5 would you recommend? Would have to be fairly low to sink a negative fault for a period until the control loop turns the system off. 100 ohm?

Comment: @CuriousDiode Check the optocoupler’s datasheet. Probably about 10 mA. On the receiver side, I used Vcc very loosely as both IC Vcc and supply voltage. The current it sinks isn’t really a part of the control loop, it’s just a mean to provide power OK signal to primary side once booted. You can’t use this verbatim.